# How to keep a range slider within a div in a flex-container

Tags: javascript, html, css, flexbox

Using Javascript, I am trying to create a grid of images, and I'd like to embed a range slider at the bottom of one of the images.  To get the grid, I am using flex-container (below I just show two numbers, 1 and 2, as examples, but in the real application they are replaced by images):

```
<style>
  .flex-container {
   display: flex;
   flex-wrap: wrap;
   background-color: LightYellow;
  }

.flex-item {
  background-color: #f1f1f1;
  width: 300px;
  margin: 10px;
  text-align: center;
  line-height: 300px;
 font-size: 30px; 
 }

</style>
<body>
 <div class="flex-container">
   <div class="flex-item">1</div>
  <div class="flex-item"> 2 </div>
</div>
</body>
```

This part works ok - I get two images side by side, as I want:

[image]

Now, suppose I'd like to add a range slide to the second div.  So I add this to my styles:

```
  .slidecontainer {
    flex: 0 1 auto;
    order: 0;
    position: relative;
    align-items: center;
    width: 100%;
   }

 .slider {
     -webkit-appearance: none;
     width: 100%;
     height: 5px;
     border-radius: 5px;
     background: #d3d3d3;
     outline: none;
     opacity: 0.7;
     -webkit-transition: .2s;
     transition: opacity .2s;
   }

  .slider:hover {
    opacity: 1;
   }

  .slider::-webkit-slider-thumb {
     -webkit-appearance: none;
     appearance: none;
     width: 25px;
     height: 15px;
     border-radius: 50%;
     background: #4CAF50;
     cursor: pointer;
    }

 .slider::-moz-range-thumb {
    width: 25px;
    height: 15px;
    border-radius: 50%;
    background: #4CAF50;
    cursor: pointer;
  }
```

and then attempt to embed the slider into one of the flex-container divs, say the second one:

```
<div class="flex-item"> 2
   <div class="slidercontainer">
     <input type="range" min="1" max="100" value="50" class="slider" id="myRange">
     <p>Value: <span id="demo"></span></p>
  </div>
</div>
```

For reasons I don't understand the images explode.  Here's what they look like now:

[image]

Is there a way to keep the dimensions of the images intact and just add the slider at the bottom of one of the images within its div?

Thanks!

Comment: To keep the slider contained in the parent div, add `margin:0;` to your `.slider` class

Comment: the main problem here is the `line-height:300px` on your `.flex-item` class

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is the HTML:

```
<div class="flex-container">
        <div class="flex-item">
            <img src="https://placeimg.com/300/150/any" alt="">
        </div>
        <div class="flex-item">
            <img src="https://placeimg.com/300/150/any" alt="">
            <div class="slidercontainer">
                <input type="range" min="1" max="100" value="50" class="slider" id="myRange">
                <p>Value: <span id="demo"></span></p>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
```

And here is the CSS:

```
img {
       max-width: 100%;
       object-fit: cover;
    }
        .flex-container {
            display: flex;
            flex-wrap: wrap;
            background-color: LightYellow;
        }

        .flex-item {
            background-color: #f1f1f1;
            width: 300px;
            margin: 10px;
            font-size: 30px;
            display: flex;
            flex-direction: column;
            align-items: center;
            justify-content: space-between;
        }

        .slidecontainer {
            flex: 0 1 auto;
            order: 0;
            position: relative;
            align-items: center;
            width: 100%;
        }

        .slider {
            -webkit-appearance: none;
            width: 100%;
            height: 5px;
            border-radius: 5px;
            background: #d3d3d3;
            outline: none;
            opacity: 0.7;
            -webkit-transition: .2s;
            transition: opacity .2s;
        }

        .slider:hover {
            opacity: 1;
        }

        .slider::-webkit-slider-thumb {
            -webkit-appearance: none;
            appearance: none;
            width: 25px;
            height: 15px;
            border-radius: 50%;
            background: #4CAF50;
            cursor: pointer;
            }

        .slider::-moz-range-thumb {
            width: 25px;
            height: 15px;
            border-radius: 50%;
            background: #4CAF50;
            cursor: pointer;
        }
```

Comment: while this "works" there's still a typo in the css `.slidecontainer` vs `class="slidercontainer"`

Comment: I just copied his html.

Comment: obviously, since you didn't find the typo, just worked around it

Answer (score 0):

It looks blown out of proportion because of the `line-height: 300px;` you have set on the `.flex-item`. Take that out and it should look more normal.

To keep the images in its native aspect ratio, simply just set the `max-width` to your width value then set `width: 100%;`. You probably want to have a div around the image too as IE11 tends to play funny with images as flex elements.